# Handling this particular string manupulation in PHP and Ruby

Tags: php, ruby

I write a lot of meta-programs. Scripts in Ruby and PHP that generate different other programming languages and structures. Example say a script that reads from CSV and generates SQL queries.

Here is a problem I have encountered many times and I always get irritated with the way I solve it.

I have an array say

```
array= %w[chris sandy jones amar kuthrapalli]
```

I need to convert this array into a string that looks like

```
chris,sandy,jones,amar,kuthrapalli
```

Now its simple to iterate and add each name to a string. But I hate to write a special condition for not putting that "last extra comma" which will other wise go there.

The beauty of "foreach" lieks loop is that we dont have to bother about indices any more but then I am forced to use the iterator with indices. (for i =0 ...blah blah blah )

May be this is the only way to solve this problem but is there a better way ?

This is a simple problem but this kind of problem manifests itself is many different ways in the work I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$my_string = implode(",",$array);
```

in php

Answer (score 1):

This is what `join` is for:

```
# chris,sandy,jones,amar,kuthrapalli
%w[chris sandy jones amar kuthrapalli].join(',')
```

PHP provides a similar function, `implode`:

```
implode(',', array('chris','sandy','jones','amar','kuthrapalli'));
```

If you need to quote the individual terms for outputting them as a comma-separated list of strings, wrap the entire thing in quotes, and join the elements with quotes/commas:

```
# 'chris','sandy','jones','amar','kuthrapalli'
"'" + %w[chris sandy jones amar kuthrapalli].join("','") + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby:

```
array.join(',')
```

In PHP, use implose as others have mentioned.

In Python: ','.join(array)